# trouble setting up redux thunk

Tags: redux, axios, redux-thunk

I have the following action creator:

```
export function selectBook(ISBN, dispatch) {
    const url = `${ROOT_ITEMS_URL}/${ISBN}?all=true`;
    dispatch({ type: 'SELECT_BOOK_LOADING', isLoading:true });
    axios.get(url)
        .then(({ data }) => dispatch({ type: 'SELECT_BOOK_SUCCESS', data}))
        .catch(( err ) => dispatch({ type: 'SELECT_BOOK_FAILURE', isLoading:false}))
}
```

I also have the following in my main index file for my project:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import LoginLayout from './layouts/LoginLayout';

import reducers from './reducers';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise, reduxThunk)(createStore);
//const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
        <LoginLayout />
    </Provider>
    , document.querySelector('.root'));
```

I am confused on how to get dispatch called into my project. I am getting the following error:

> bundle.js:5690 Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function

When I call this function I am not passing any dispatch. But I am not sure how to call dispatch into it. Is it a redux call I need to make with my function call?

```
this.props.selectBook(params.bookID);
```

Should it be this instead?:

```
this.props.selectBook(params.bookID, dispatch);
```

and what import is dispatch with? import dispatch from 'redux'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dispatch` is given to you for free via `redux-thunk`. The trick here is that your action creator should return a *function*, and the first argument to the function will be `dispatch`. Your action creator will end up looking like this:

```
export function selectBook(ISBN) {
  return dispatch => {
    const url = `${ROOT_ITEMS_URL}/${ISBN}?all=true`;
    dispatch({ type: 'SELECT_BOOK_LOADING', isLoading:true });
    axios.get(url)
      .then(({ data }) => dispatch({ type: 'SELECT_BOOK_SUCCESS', data}))
      .catch(( err ) => dispatch({ type: 'SELECT_BOOK_FAILURE', isLoading:false}))
  }
}
```

Comment: I am marking this one correct because it does not say to use axios with this. Technically that is incorrect, but both answers were right in saying I needed return dispatch around my axios call. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do your action creator like that:
`` export function selectBook(ISBN) {
    const url = `${ROOT_ITEMS_URL}/${ISBN}?all=true`;
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: 'SELECT_BOOK_LOADING', isLoading:true });
        axios.get(url)
            .then(({ data }) => dispatch({ type: 'SELECT_BOOK_SUCCESS', data}))
            .catch(( err ) => dispatch({ type: 'SELECT_BOOK_FAILURE', isLoading:false}))
    }
} ``
It needs to return function